# Child process is blocked by full pipe, cannot read in parent process

Tags: c++, fork, parent-child, pipe

I have roughly created the following code to call a child process:

```
// pipe meanings
const int READ = 0;
const int WRITE = 1;

int fd[2];
// Create pipes
if (pipe(fd))
  {
    throw ...
  }
p_pid = fork();
if (p_pid == 0) // in the child
  {
    close(fd[READ]);
    if (dup2(fd[WRITE], fileno(stdout)) == -1)
      {
        throw ...
      }
    close(fd[WRITE]);

    // Call exec
    execv(argv[0], const_cast<char*const*>(&argv[0]));
    _exit(-1);
  }
else if (p_pid < 0) // fork has failed
  {
    throw
  }
else // in th parent
  {
      close(fd[WRITE]);
      p_stdout = new std::ifstream(fd[READ]));
  }
```

Now, if the subprocess does not write too much to stdout, I can wait for it to finish and then read the stdout from `p_stdout`. If it writes too much, the write blocks and the parent waits for it forever.
To fix this, I tried to wait with `WNOHANG` in the parent, if it is not finished, read all available output from p_stdout using `readsome`, sleep a bit and try again. Unfortunately, `readsome` never reads anything:

```
while (true)
  {
    if (waitid(P_PID, p_pid, &info, WEXITED | WNOHANG) != 0)
      throw ...;
    else if (info.si_pid != 0) // waiting has succeeded
      break;

    char tmp[1024];
    size_t sizeRead;
    sizeRead = p_stdout->readsome(tmp, 1024);
    if (sizeRead > 0)
      s_stdout.write(tmp, sizeRead);
    sleep(1);
  }
```

The question is: Why does this not work and how can I fix it?

**edit:** If there is only child, simply using `read` instead of `readsome` would probably work, but the process has multiple children and needs to react as soon as one of them terminates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sarnold suggested, you need to change the order of your calls.  Read first, wait last.  Even if your method worked, you might miss the last read. i.e. you exit the loop before you read the last set of bytes that was written.

The problem might be is that ifstream is non-blocking.  I've never liked iostreams, even in my C++ projects, I always liked the simplicity of C's stdio functions (i.e. FILE*, fprintf, etc).  One way to get around this is to read if the descriptor is readable.  You can use select to determine if there is data waiting on that pipe.  You're going to need select if you are going to read from multiple children anyway, so might as well learn it now.

As for a quick isreadable function, try something like this (please note I haven't tried compiling this):

```
bool isreadable(int fd, int timeoutSecs)
{
    struct timeval tv = { timeoutSecs, 0 };
    fd_set readSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    return select(fds, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &tv) == 1;
}
```

Then in your parent code, do something like:

```
while (true) {
    if (isreadable(fd[READ], 1)) {
        // read fd[READ];
        if (bytes <= 0)
            break;
    }
}

wait(pid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest re-writing the code so that it doesn't call `waitpid(2)` until *after* `read(2)` calls on the pipe return `0` to signify end-of-file. Once you get the end-of-file return from your read calls, you know the child is dead, and you can finally `waitpid(2)` for it.

Another option is to de-couple the reading from the reaping even further and perform the wait calls in a `SIGCHLD` signal handler asynchronously to the reading operations.

Comment: Sorry, I was being imprecise in the question. I need to use `readsome` instead of `read`, since the process has multiple children and using `read` would block until the output is available.

Comment: About the reading part, yes, you are right, I should probably do this before. Right now, I try to read the rest of the output after I know that the child process has terminated, perhaps I should order this differently. Would it make a difference, though?
Unfortunately, I do not understand what you mean by the SIGCHLD handler. Would you have a link to an explanation for me?

Comment: For the multiple-children issue: sounds like it is time to break out `select(2)` -- perfect for exactly this task. The `select_tut(2)` manpage will be a _gigantic_ assistance the first few times.

Comment: OK, I will read up on this. I was hoping that I could use a C++ stream as above, and would not have to resort to C functions for the pipe.

Comment: For the "perhaps I should order this differently" -- if your child programs ever intend to write more `PIPE_BUF` bytes (4096 bytes is mentioned in my `pipe(7)` manpage) then they will stall until the data in their pipe has been consumed. They won't die until you've read enough for them to fill the remaining kernel buffer and resume writing.

Comment: I don't know much about the C++ stream functions -- I presume they _should_ work as advertised -- but since the POSIX APIs are how the processes interact with the kernel, that's what I'm mentioning. Sorry about the disconnect but I know where I stand with the POSIX APIs. :)

Comment: Well yes, this is exactly the problem I am experiencing - otherwise the code works just fine. But note that I use `waitid` with `WNOHANG`, which always returns immediately, so the order does not really matter. The problem is that the C++ iostream::readsome somehow never reads data, although the pipe already contains 4096 bytes. Any ideas on this?

Comment: For the signal handler, you need to install a function via `sigaction(2)` for the `SIGCHLD` signal. The kernel will arrange for your function to run whenever one of your children die. You're extremely limited in what operations you can perform in the handler -- for that, see the `signal(7)` manpage (or [the OpenGroup docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04)). Generally you just `wait(2)` in the handler and make note of the status for the rest of your program to use later.

Comment: Ooh, an idea: `readsome` doesn't appear to be working, but you're not checking the error status of the stream. [cplusplus has a guide on that](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/readsome/), but as usual, cplusplus.com isn't definitive by any measure, so use whatever better documentation you've got for the `ios` error bits. I'm getting bleary-eyed, so it's bedtime for me. Edit the question with the results of error checking so it'll be more visible for others who will take my place. :)

Comment: Very good idea, thank you, but that's not it. If I clear the status of the stream before readsome, it does not improve. Also, the status of the stream is always good.